# NHibernate ISession.Update

Tags: nhibernate, session

I have noticed, by using log4net, that when calling ISession.Update, it updates all the changed objects.

For example:

```
// Change 2 instances 
user1.IsDeleted = true;
user2.UserName = "Xyz";
// Call session.Update to update the 2 users
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Session.Update(user1); // This updates both user1 & user2
    transaction.Commit();
}
using (ITransaction transaction = session.BeginTransaction())
{
    Session.Update(user2); // Now there is no need for this
    transaction.Commit();
}
```

Is this the default behavior of NHibernate or has something to do with my mapping file?

Can I make NHibernate update one by one?

Comment: Do you use multiple transactions per session? And why do you get the user before starting the transaction?

Comment: Yes multiple transactions per session. I always leave the session open and use a new transaction for each operation. I get the User instance by calling session.Get, pass the user to the UI to make changes then update it.

Comment: Why do you use a separate transaction for each operation? That sound very strange.

Comment: Any suggestion for session and transaction management in NHibernate. I basically have a UserRepository that considers each operation as a unit of work and persist to the DB once it is finished. So adding/updating a user opens a new transaction and saves/updates the user then commit or rollback in case of exception.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's the [**normal**](http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing) and [**default behavior**](http://brian.pontarelli.com/2007/04/03/hibernate-pitfalls-part-2/):

> Hibernate maintains a cache of Objects
>   that have been inserted, updated or
>   deleted. It also maintains a cache of
>   Objects that have been queried from
>   the database. These Objects are
>   referred to as persistent Objects as
>   long as the EntityManager that was
>   used to fetch them is still active.
>   What this means is that any changes to
>   these Objects within the bounds of a
>   transaction are automatically
>   persisted when the transaction is
>   committed. These updates are implicit
>   within the boundary of the transaction
>   and you don’t have to explicitly call
>   any method to persist the values.

From [**Hibernate Pitfalls part 2**](http://www.tobinharris.com/2007/2/3/nhibernate-faq):

> Q) Do I still have to do Save and
>   Update inside transactions?
>
> Save() is only needed for objects that
>   are not persistent (such as new
>   objects). You can use Update to bring
>   an object that has been evicted back
>   into a session.

From [**NHibernate's automatic (dirty checking) update behaviour**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/673564/nhibernates-automatic-dirty-checking-update-behaviour-turning-it-off)**:**

> I've just discovered that if I get an
>   object from an NHibernate session and
>   change a property on object,
>   NHibernate will automatically update
>   the object on commit without me
>   calling Session.Update(myObj)!
>
> **Answer:** You can set Session.FlushMode to
>   FlushMode.Never. This will make your
>   operations explicit ie: on tx.Commit() or session.Flush().
>   Of course this will still update the
>   database upon commit/flush. If you do
>   not want this behavior, then call
>   session.Evict(yourObj) and it will
>   then become transient and NHibernate
>   will not issue any db commands for it.

Comment: Just to make sure I understand, setting the Session.FlushMode to FlushMode.Never then calling Session.Update will update only user1 in my example.

Comment: @sh_kamalh Although I'd prefer Evict(obj), take a loot at http://nhforge.org/doc/nh/en/index.html#manipulatingdata-flushing

Comment: Sorry for taking that much to mark this as answer. But I was not quite understanding the concepts of NHibernate. Evict is working correctly.

Answer (score 2):

This is the default behavior when FlushMode of session is Auto or Commit.

In these cases calling transaction.Commit() flushes the session & updates ALL persistent objects

So if you remove the calls Session.Update it wouldn't make any difference

> Can I make NHibernate update one by one?

Yes. use FlushMode.Never or postpone commiting the session if possible. I guess you don't need to use Evict for this case